# Question about measure on set that is not in $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, definition

I think I have problem with badly written book, or I just can't understand statement.

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be any measure space and $\mu^*$ be outer and $\mu_*$ inner measure inner measure generated by $\mu$. Then it's true for any $A\subseteq X$:$$\mu_*(A)\leq \mu(A)\leq\mu^*(A)$$

*line under this one is $\mu_*(A)=\mu(A)=\mu^*(A)$ if $A\in\mathcal{A}$

And it's nowhere defined what is $\mu(A)$ for set $A$ that is not from $\mathcal{A}$.
What would be definition? How should I "treat" it?

(This inequality is used to prove theorem that A is from completion of $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ if and only if $\mu_*(A)=\mu^*(A)$, so if someone has link to proof f that theorem (since proof from mine book obviously has flaws)I would be grateful =))

Comment: Probably they mean “$μ_*(A) ≤ μ^* (A)$ and $μ_*(A) ≤ μ(A) ≤ μ^*(A)$ if $A ∈ \mathcal{A}$”.

Comment: From the brief quotation (from a secret source) we cannot guess what is going on.

Comment: It's book in Croatian so I think source wouldn't help :P
But I added some info.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion would be correct if instead of $A\subset X$ it would say $A\in\mathcal A$. As you say, the way it is written makes no sense.

Comment: line under this one is $\mu_*(A)=\mu(A)=\mu^*(A) $ if $A\in\mathcal{A}$ so I still think they somehow "expanded \mu". This is also used for proving one theorem so it bugs me even more...

Comment: That's expected.  If you construct an outer and an inner measure out of $\mu$, you would expect them to agree with $\mu$ on $\mathcal A$.